# Error at offset for unserializing data (usual solutions tried)

Tags: php, json, serialization

I'm pulling 2 feeds of images, from Instagram and Facebook. For both, I end up with arrays like below that I combine and store in MySQL.

```
 [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10151385447249771
        [small] => http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s320x320/602882_10151385447249771_875867185_n.jpg
        [large] => http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s600x600/602882_10151385447249771_875867185_n.jpg
        [date] => 1359526678
        [date_display] => 5:17 pm, 30 Jan 2013
        [name] => Something cool
        [link] => http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151385447249771&set=a.10151385444664771.496088.112462694770&type=1
        [caption] => Photo by Jimbo James
        [type] => facebook
    )
```

Then I do the following:

```
$photos = array_merge($facebook_photos,$instagram_photos);

usort($photos, array($this, "sort_photos"));

$photos = array_reverse($photos);
```

If I output the array here, it's fine. I can also serialise and unserialize and it's fine

However, after I store it in MySQL and then pull it out and unserialize, I get 'error at offset' messages.

```
return mb_unserialize($feed['data']);

public function mb_unserialize($serial_str) { 
    $out = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $serial_str ); 
    $out = unserialize($out); 
    return  json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($out)), true);
}
```

I'm using BLOB column to store the data. I've tried base64 encoding/decoding and also storing as JSON. Any other ideas?

Comment: You mean, you still `serialize()` you just wrap `base64` or `json_encode()` around it? Or you've stored the array as plain JSON or `base64`? Can you provide a failing output string from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: BLOB wasn't big enough. I changed it to LONGBLOB and voila.